# Why is my note.js app not responsive on Apache reverse proxy?

Tags: node.js, express, apache, socket.io, reverse-proxy

When I open my website on the directory I assigned for the node.js app(for example domain.com/node) it just shows the html file not the responsive node.js app.
When i try to access it using the port like ip:port it works fine, so I think its my Apache config.
The app uses Express and socket.io and I tried using Cors but it dosent affect the outcome.

My Apache Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName jutechs.de

   SSLProxyEngine On
   SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
   SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyVia Full

 <Proxy *>
    Require all granted
 </Proxy>

 <Location /textEdit>
  ProxyPass https://127.0.0.1:2096
  ProxyPassReverse  https://127.0.0.1:2096
</Location>

  <Directory "/var/www/html/textEdit">
     AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

To get more in detail whats happening:
For example the Connected user counter stays 0 when I connect, but works on IP:port but not domain/node

As I said before I tryed using Cors since I thought it may just not take Post/Get request from the Reverse Proxy but it didnt change.